# nginx redirects instead of proxying

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have Ubuntu 16.04, nginx as web server, apache2 with wordpress for wordpress site.

I am trying to setup nginx for multiple sites.

- One site is static, works all the time.
- Second is basically proxy to apache2 with wordpress.

Now, when I access to server e.g. `http://example.com`, it should open word press.

My VirtualHost for apache looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

What ever I tried, and I tried a lot, each time I make it work, it redirects me from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com:8080`.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You need to fix your WordPress configuration.

Comment: Why do you use Apache at all? If the setup is not more complicated than what you actually posted, I would suggest you install php-fpm to proxy PHP-requests directly to that one instead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you might be right, I had siteurl and home set with port. Anyway, still not working after change.

Comment: @pkhamre I do not know anything else working with WP, never needed it. I'll check it. If you have some source, please let me know. I plan to use php7 for this

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not working. I still getting redirected to 8080 somehow.

Comment: @pkhamre I've used your suggestion, and it works. Thank you very much. You saved my time a lot. Still, I would like to know to perform what I tried. I will leave this question open for now, because it really took my time and I do not want it wasted without answer, if possible.